# I need to save/compile a few times and a bunch of weird files (like foo.tex.Ak6664) appear in my Dropbox folder each time

Tags: texstudio, auxiliary-files, bugs, dropbox

I need to compile between two and four times before I see changes I make in the editor (TeXstudio) and each time I compile, a new `.tex` file is created with random letters and numbers at the end.

For example, If I create the file `hello.tex` and compile two to four times I'll get the file,

```
 hello.tex.QU6664
```

then I make some small changes in the editor and compile two to four times I'll get the additional file,

```
 hello.tex.Ak6664
```

After continuing to do this (each time compiling between two to four times before I see the changes I made), I now have many files that look like

```
hello.tex.QU6664, hello.tex.Ak6664, hello.tex.YX6664, hello.tex.sN6664, hello.tex.Ss6664, ...
```

A little bit of additional information (in case it's relevant): Everything was working fine up until a few days ago, i.e. only needed to compile once and only the file `hello.tex` was created. I still only get one `.aux`,  `.synctex` and `.pdf` files. I use TeXstudio to write and compile. I don't think it has anything to do with the bibliography (I tried removing bibliography altogether and still having the same problem).

How do I prevent these additional files from appearing and only compiling once like I used to? Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Something changed. You did the change. Track the change. Without knowing what is inside *those weird auxiliary files*, how are we supposed to help? The psychic squad is currently on vacation.

Comment: @Johannes_B The changes I make are in texstudio. Say a sentence was "hello there" and then I change it to "hello there sir" then the above will happen.

Comment: @Johannes_B I am on this site asking for help because I have a problem that I cannot solve. If my question is not clear or doesn't make sense then you can tell me and I'll try to clarify. I understand that it is probably something I changed, and I am on this website trying to figure out what I may have done to cause this problem and how to fix it. I thought your comment was rude and did not help (and is quite hurtful).

Comment: We can't help you without knowing the contents of `hello.tex`.

Comment: @Hugh Okay. I understand. Unfortunately, the file is a very long one that I cannot post here. I also went to some of my other files that compiled just fine a few days ago and literally just added a letter and the same thing happened.

Comment: Do you get the same extra files appearing with a new document consisting of `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} Foo \end{document}`?

Comment: I am sorry that you are hurt by my comment. But your question gives no clue about what is going on. You could just as well ask why your car does not start. You stated that the tex file created is *weird*. Why is it weird? Are there some crazy Cthulhu signs in there? You gota give us *something*.

Comment: @DaiBowen and @Johannes_B It works fine with just `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} Foo \end{document}`. When I remove all the text from the document that doesn't work (leaving all the stuff before \begin{document}) it also works fine. However, it also happens in all my other documents when I just add a letter (that were compiling fine a few days ago).... I think it all started when I was playing around with \bibliography{biblio} and \theendnotes... I will try remove things from the file that isn't working and see if I can figure out what is causing the problem.

Comment: it sounds like something has happened to the editor itself.  have you made any system changes?  or have you perhaps received some weird mail and clicked on a link you didn't recognize?  this doesn't sound like a tex problem.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for the apology. It's appreciated... it's just that before after compiling I got one .tex file and each time I recompiled (after some changes) it just replaced the .tex files. Now I'm getting additional .tex file with things at the end like .tex.Pd664. When I click on these files I cannot open them (the message is "Unable to find software to open this file...").

Comment: Open them with notepad or any other text editor.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm quite sure I didn't make any system changes. However, it may be something that I clicked on. I ran my antivirus (panda) and it couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Johannes_B I opened them with a text editor and it just seems like the exact same text that was in the original file i.e. nothing seems out of the ordinary.

Comment: Okay. I figured out what's causing the problem - Dropbox. When I copied the files onto my desktop then it worked fine.... I think the reason is that I went over my space capacity and although I've now deleted files to have additional space, it might take dropbox a few days to update.... thanks for all the help and sorry it was an irrelevant (and / or stupid and / or unclear) question!

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to your own (not stupid) question, and put "dropbox" into the title and fix the tags. Someone else might run into the same problem and find the solution here.

Comment: @user103828 I edited your question a bit in order to make it more easily findable and more helpful for users with the same problem, even though it might not exactly match your problem/perception of the problem anymore; hope you don’t mind. Among other things, I removed the bit about the `.ent` file – these are usually generated by the package [`endnotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/endnotes), see e.g. [this list](https://github.com/wspr/latex-auxfiles).

Comment: This was the first report of that special problem. By now a couple of users asked the same question.

Comment: @user103828 I thought I am the only one who had this problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have the same problem. According to the [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1933/), it seems to be related to a change in the way TeXstudio saves a file. What can you do? Two options:

## a) Give up the cloud

... and simply work outside your Dropbox, as the OP suggested. You can still manually copy files into the Dropbox to back them up or share them.

## b) Downgrade TeXstudio and keep the cloud

My (hopefully just temporary) solution: Downgrade to [TeXstudio 2.10.8](https://sourceforge.net/projects/texstudio/files/texstudio/TeXstudio%202.10.8/), which saves files the old way. I’m using the portable version in order to be able to run it alongside the current one.

Transferring your settings to the portable version is really easy: [Find the settings file `texstudio.ini`](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-the-settings-stored) and copy it to the directory of the portable version. (TeXstudio needs to be *closed* while you do that.) I’m not sure if you also need to import the `.txsprofile` file, if somebody can clarify that, let me know!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Until the bug is fixed (hopefully soon), I think I'll just work on my desktop and copy the files into dropbox at the end of the day!

Comment: @user103828 That works as well, of course, if you don’t need/want the convenient ongoing cloud-backup, I’ll add that to the answer

Answer (score 7):

Dropbox was creating these additional files (not sure exactly why) due to space capacity constraints. Small files were not causing any issues. Everything works fine on my desktop. Although I now have enough capacity on dropbox, I think it takes dropbox a few days to update.

**Edit1:**

- It turns out that this is a texstudio bug and not a problem with dropbox (and that my solution is incorrect) - see @UlrikeFischer link in the comments below.
- I plan to just work on my desktop anyway and copy files to dropbox at the end of the day until the bug is fixed (hopefully soon). Alternatively, I'm sure @doncherry solution also works.

**Edit2:** I stopped working on the desktop and downgraded texstudio like @doncherry suggested.

Comment: It seems to be a texstudio bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1933/

Comment: It is not related to your Dropbox capacity. I have the same issue and I have only used 10% of my capacity

Answer (score 5):

Version 2.12.0 has solved the issue. The [changelog file](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/CHANGELOG.txt) includes the line

> TeXstudio 2.12.0 
>   [...] 
>   - revert to pre 2.11.0 save method on Windows because the new QSaveFile has problems with Dropbox folders

I have checked and it does work for me on Windows 10.