# TexStudio or MikTex problem: extra files (not the normal ones)

Tags: texstudio, dropbox

A few days ago, my TexStudio (which I have used without difficulty for years) started being slow compiling, not compiling when I hit the "build and view" and "build buttons", and saving these strange extra files when it finally does go through. Again, these are not the usual extra files, like the ".aux" file. They look like maybe they are failed save attempts. It is doing this for every project I work on, even old ones I pull up that have pretty different preambles. Here are examples:

> Cover Letter Template 1.tex.b10756
>
> Cover Letter Template 1.tex.r10756

Anyone know what has gone wrong, and how I can fix it? I've had no luck searching for other people having this problem, or from any other help source.

Comment: We had another very similar question recently: these files aren't inside a DropBox folder, perchance?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336541/i-need-to-compile-a-few-times-and-a-bunch-of-weird-auxiliary-files-appear-in-my

Comment: Yes, it is in dropbox. Thanks for find this! And thanks for the help in general!I searched hours yesterday, looking for someone else with this problem, I guess I just didn't use the right keywords. 

However, I'm still not sure how to fix the issue. My dropbox isn't anywhere near full, the way the other poster's was; I have a gig of space. And it has been working fine for years.

I don't want to give up backing up my files in dropbox, and I don't love the idea of having to move the files to someplace local everytime I open something. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well the random extension suggests some automatic backup system going haywire. As you both used texstudio you should perhaps try another editor to check if texstudio is part of the problem. actually there is already a bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1933/

Comment: Thanks! I checked just on tex works, and it is not having the same problem. I'm going to go back to the old version of TS to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Clunky workaround that may let you keep the new texstudio: compile from the command line?

Comment: @EthanBolker That won’t work, unfortunately, because the problem is about saving the file, not compiling (which requires previous saving, naturally).