# Files won't save unless force is applied

Tags: compiling, texstudio, dropbox

I'm currently working on my Thesis in LaTex and have successfully used TexStudio (2.11.2) and MiKTeX (2.9.6069-x64) for two years now. Since a couple of days TexStudio always needs to be *forced* to save the File by holding down STRG+S for 3-4 seconds and when I compile my file any changes since that last forced save are not included but an older version of the Code is compiled.

I also noticed that everytime I compile the code a new copy of my .tex-file with an obscure file-ending is created (Base File is "Thesis.tex"; new Files are e.g. "Thesis.tex.if2720", "Thesis.tex.JC2720" et cetera).

Cutting almost all text from the file won't change anything, updating packages and completely wiping MiKTeX and TexStudio didn't help. Neither cutting  TexWorks does not suffer from the same problem.

Additional Information: The Files are saved inside a Dropbox-folder and I am using Windows File History for backup.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: The next one. texstudio messed up the file saving.  See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336541/i-need-to-save-compile-a-few-times-and-a-bunch-of-weird-files-like-foo-tex-ak66 and the bug reports one the texstudio bug tracker.

Comment: Many thanks for that hint :-). Downgrading resolved the issue for now.