# Unwanted and uneeded files generated every save

Tags: texstudio, files

Just in case this is relevant: I've set up git on a Windows PC and every time I edit and save a change in a LaTex file (using Tex Studio) a new .tex file is created. See here:

[image]

'The_Cult' is the original LaTex file and the file below it is the new file.

Every time I make any edit and save one of these files is created.

This makes for a very messy work folder.

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can prevent it?

Comment: My guess is that you store the files in a dropbox folder. If yes, see [this answer to "I need to save/compile a few times and a bunch of weird files (like foo.tex.Ak6664) appear in my Dropbox folder each time"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336603/110998).

Comment: @gernot yeah, I am saving in Dropbox. Great spot. Thanks for the heads up.