# A lot of files created when saving

Tags: texstudio, dropbox

Each time I save (sometimes I have to press save more than once to actually save the document) one aditional file is created "document.tex.something". Does anybody know why this happens? How can I solve this?
[image]

I use TeXstudio, by the way.

Comment: Could be backup/undo files created by the editor. Maybe check the settings if there's an option for this your can disable.

Comment: @siracusa I don't find any option to check or uncheck backup of files.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336541/i-need-to-save-compile-a-few-times-and-a-bunch-of-weird-files-like-foo-tex-ak66

Comment: @Johannes_B Thank you very much. I uninstalled TeXstudio and installed it again and now works fine, but if that happens again, I will know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

As [Johannes_B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/37907/johannes-b) pointed, the solution is in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336541/i-need-to-save-compile-a-few-times-and-a-bunch-of-weird-files-like-foo-tex-ak66). The best option is to downgrade to TeXstudio [2.10.8](https://sourceforge.net/projects/texstudio/files/texstudio/TeXstudio%202.10.8/) and the problem is solved.