# PDF not updating in TeXstudio

Tags: xetex, texlive, texstudio, windows

I'm having some problems with TeXstudio on Windows 7. I am running the newest version (2.11.2) and I just installed TeX Live. I am running a dual screen setup and I want the code on one screen and the PDF on the other screen. I've set both the "Default Viewer" and the "PDF Viewever" to "Internal PDF Viewer (Windowed)".

When I change something in a .tex file and run the command "Build & View" the PDF does not change. If I close the PDF window and run "Build & View" it does not update the changes either. It seems like the problem is that when I compile and view, the .tex file is not saved. If I save the .tex file manually by pressing the disk and then press "Build & View" it seems to work.

How do I make it do this automatically?

Comment: Since you haven't posted an MWE, I presume that  you may be compiling your document that is in dropbox, drive, etc., If so please make sure that you save your document until the disk symbol over your document goes off. Else, you save all your documents to a local disk (out of dropbox, drive, etc.,) and try to compile. I suppose it should work (from my personal experience). Finally, I do face the same problem when I work in dropbox, drives etc.,. Hope this helps !!

Comment: Hi Raaja
Thanks for your reply. I thought it didn't make sense to make a MWE since it's all my documents I am having this problem with. I am indeed compiling in my Dropbox and it worked working locally, but that is not really a solution - if you ask me. I am working on both MacOS and Windows, and I have never experienced this problem on MacOS - so it must be a bug in TeXstudio for Windows or something that should be set up. It makes no sense that it is necessary to hit the save button multiple times in order to compile a PDF, just because you are working from Dropbox

Comment: Yes ofcourse it is a bug :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed doncherry's advice [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336541/i-need-to-save-compile-a-few-times-and-a-bunch-of-weird-files-like-foo-tex-ak66) and downgraded to 2.10.8 and now it works.