# pdflatex won't write in certain folders

Tags: errors, compiling

I have TexLive on Windows 10 installed. For some reason, it can only write to files in certain folders, and not others.
I am using the command:  `pdflatex sample2e.tex`
This uses a sample document that comes with TexLive for testing. The file can be found here: http://www.wikiupload.com/UFRD0WK19701I6J

I get the following output in these folders (i.e. it works): `C:\Users\josh_`,`C:\Users\josh_\testing`, `C:\testing`

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/sample2e.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.13> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./sample2e.aux)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd) [1{c:/texlive/2016/texmf-
var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] [3] (./sample2e.aux) )<c:/texlive/
2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><c:/texlive/2016/texm
f-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb><c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1
/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb><c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/am
sfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmr12.pfb><c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb>
<c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr6.pfb><c:/texlive
/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb><c:/texlive/2016/texmf
-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb><c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts
/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb><c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/pu
blic/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb><c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfo
nts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on sample2e.pdf (3 pages, 136743 bytes).
Transcript written on sample2e.log.
```

However, I get the following output in these folders (i.e. it doesn't work): `C:\Users\josh_\Documents\tester`, `C:\Users\josh_\Documents`, `C:\Users\josh_\Dropbox`, `C:\Users\josh_\Dropbox\tester`, `C:\Users\josh_\Desktop`, `C:\Users\josh_\Desktop\testing`

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't write on file `sample2e.log'.
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-Z to exit; default file extension is `.log')
Please type another transcript file name:
```

Can you tell me what is going on and how to fix it?

I particularly want to work in my Dropbox folders.

Thanks

Comment: Added the file. Yes, I can write to the folders where I get the error message. I am the sole administrator and I only have one account on the computer. I can't get rid of the `_`. Windows, in all its wisdom, gave "josh_" as the folder name when I first set up the computer. It is rather ridiculous. To clarify, I first `cd` into the folder and then run the command.

Comment: is there an existing sample2e.log there?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Isn't there a known issue with Dropbox?

Comment: @cfr perhaps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336541/i-need-to-save-compile-a-few-times-and-a-bunch-of-weird-files-like-foo-tex-ak66

Comment: You have a mixed up tex system. The binary claims it is from tl17, the files are from tl16. Beside this: all the problematic are special folders where the name and the location can be different. What is your locale?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There is only an existing sample2e.log file in the folders where it works as I have run pdflatex more than once. It is not there in the folders where it does not work as pdflatex was never able to write it to begin with. Thus, the problem seems not to be in rewriting over the log file, but in writing it to begin with.

Comment: @cfr , DavidCarlisle While some of it could be related to Dropbox, it also doesn't work in my Documents folder. Also, I am running the command in the command line, so TexStudio shouldn't be causing problems. I had switched to the command line as TexStudio wasn't compiling either and I wanted to determine whether it was pdflatex or TexStudio. Unfortunately, pdflatex itself wasn't working.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok. What problems will these differences cause?    Good point about the special folders. It is weird that it worked the last time I was using it (several months ago), though. My locale is `English (Canada)`.

Comment: Should I just try to reinstall Latex and/or TexLive? I was hoping to avoid this as it takes a long time to download everything. This should fix the differences between the binaries and files (though I get the same issue in the special folders with a blank `test.tex` file). Reinstalling may also get pdflatex to play more nicely with Windows' special folders. (I hope...)

Comment: I have no idea. Currently I'm only looking for a pattern. To me it looks as if you have no writing rights in this folders. What happens if you do in the command line (the same you used for a failed pdflatex run) in one of this folder  `echo "blb" > sometestfile.txt`? Is the file created?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In the failed folders, I ran `echo "blb" > sometestfile.txt` and then `more sometestfile.txt` to verify the contents. It worked without issue in all of the folders. Thus, I do have writing rights.

Comment: Do you have any idea why your pdflatex (when it runs) picks up files in a texlive2016 folder? (The format itself seems to be from a 2017 system).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer When I first installed TexLive, it was 2016. The two most recent updates performed by the TexLive manager are from 2017. It is a bit odd that TexLive would update pdflatex to a version that is problematic. But, perhaps it is a bug that hasn't been caught yet or will go away with reinstallation. I am really starting to think a full reinstall of TexLive (and TexStudio for safe measure) is warranted :(

Comment: TeXlive doesn't update/upgrade a 2016 to 2017. I have both and they are in parallel folder. Perhaps you installed the 2017 over the 2016. That's curious but I doubt that is the reason of the blocked folders. Do you have some antivirus or firewall system or something like that tries to protect the folders?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Bingo! I have Bitdefender Total Security 2018 and when I opened it, it had notifications stating that it had blocked pdflatex from writing in a protected folder. It told it to allow the program and now it works. I was not expecting it to protect the folders like this. Oh, well. Thank you for your help! Do you want to write the comment up as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Thank you to cfr and David Carlisle for your help as well!

Comment: Better write an answer yourself.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok. Will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My antivirus/firewall program Bitdefender Total Security 2018 has the above "failed" folders protected.
Upon opening the program it gave notifications that it had blocked `pdflatex` from writing to certain protected folders.

I then told Bitdefender to allow pdflatex to write to protected folders by doing the following:
1. Open Bitdefender.
2. Go to the main screen (icon is a "B" inside a shield).
3. Click on `View Features`.
4. Click on `Application Access` in the `Safe Files` box at the bottom right of the interface.
5. The blocked program(s) will be listed as "blocked". Click the toggle switch to set them to "allowed".

After this, pdflatex could write to the "failed" folders listed above.

Thanks to everyone for your help!
A big thank you to Ulrike Fischer for the key insight of looking for a program that is protecting the folders!

Answer (score 1):

I just bought a laptop with Windows 10
and installed TeXlive.2021.

errors:

- cannot run texhash.exe from icon nor batch file

  - solution:
    navigate to
    C:...\texlive\2021\bin\win32
    select texhash.exe, run as Administrator

alternate: edit the various files
C:/.../texlive/texmf-local/ls-R to write.
C:/.../texlive/2021/texmf-config/ls-R to write.
C:/.../texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R to write.
C:/.../texlive/2021/texmf-dist/ls-R to write.

- cannot write .log

solution: turn on access to controlled folders:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/allow-an-app-to-access-controlled-folders-b5b6627a-b008-2ca2-7931-7e51e912b034

Controlled folder access in Windows Security reviews the apps that can make changes to files in protected folders and blocks unauthorized or unsafe apps from accessing or changing files in those folders.

Select Start

> Settings
> Update & Security
> > Windows Security
> > Virus & threat protection.

Under Virus & threat protection settings,
select Manage settings.

Under Controlled folder access,
select Manage Controlled folder access.

Switch the Controlled folder access setting
to On or Off.

Ron Fehd